# Finding the asymptotic of the sequence $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{f(a_n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

We define $f(x)$ be a differentiable function with $f^\prime\ge 0$, $f^\prime$ bounded and $f\to+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$. Define the sequence $\{a_n\}$ as follows:
$$a_0=1, a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{f(a_n)},n\in\mathbb{N}_+.$$
My question is, how can we find the asymptotic of $a_n$? For instance, if $f(x)=x$, then clearly
$f(x)$ satisfies the conditions and the sequence turned out to be
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n},$$
which we may give an estimate that $a_n=\sqrt{2n}+o(\sqrt{2n})$. However, what about a randomly chosen $f$? How can we compute the asymptotic of $\{a_n\}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $a_n = \sqrt{2n} + \mathcal{o}(\sqrt{n})$ is not a closed form of $a_n$. Perhaps you mean to find the **asymptotic** (closed-form) of $a_n$

Comment: @NN2 You are right. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that $f$ is strictly positive for $x \ge 1$. Then $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing with $a_n \to +\infty$.

The *idea* of the following calculation is to show that the sequence $(a_n)$ behaves roughly like the solution $y$ of the differential equation $y' = 1/f(y)$, which is given by $F(y(t)) = t$ where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

Define $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$. Then
$$
 F(a_{n+1}) - F(a_n) = \int_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}} f(t) \, dt 
\ge f(a_n) (a_{n+1}-a_n) = 1
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
 F(a_{n+1}) - F(a_n)  &\le f(a_{n+1}) (a_{n+1}-a_n) \\
&= 1 + (f(a_{n+1})-f(a_n))(a_{n+1}-a_n) \\
&\le 1 + M (a_{n+1}-a_n)^2 \\
&= 1 + \frac{M}{f(a_n)^2}
\end{align}
$$
where $M$ is an upper bound for $f'$. It follows that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} F(a_{n+1}) - F(a_n) = 1 \, .
$$
By the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), this implies that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F(a_n)}{n} = 1 \, ,
$$
i.e. $a_n \sim F^{-1}(n)$.

*Example:* For $f(x) = x$ we get $F(x) = x^2/2$ and therefore $a_n \sim \sqrt{2n}$.